# What is the biblical basis for the term 'the lost'?

Tags: biblical-basis, soteriology, terminology

Is there a passage that denotes some group of God's creation as 'lost'? Or is it a made up term that has *little foundation* in the text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Luke 19:10 is the most salient passage:

> For the Son of Man has come to seek and to save the lost.

Jesus also refers to the "lost sheep of Israel":

> Matthew 10:6: Instead, go to the lost sheep of the house of Israel.
>
> Matthew 15:24: He replied, “I was sent only to the lost sheep of the house of Israel.”

And there are the three "lost" parables of Luke 15: the Lost Sheep, the Lost Coin, and the Lost/Prodigal Son.

Comment: -1 already lol. interesting that the term (from the verses you quote) has quite a favourable light shining on it - not the idea of doom that is generally associated.

Comment: @user47952 Well the hope is the Gospel, but Jesus is clear elsewhere what awaits those who reject him.

Comment: @curiousdannii [This article](https://thinktheology.co.uk/blog/article/what_if_the_lost_sheep_isnt_an_unbeliever_and_the_shepherd_isnt_jesus) is quite interesting, highlighting 2 different meaning of the "lost" (Matt 18 vs. Luke 15).